# Tracking actions taken on an object - proven way?

Tags: c#

Let's face it, some of the time you can get away with simply tracking exceptions and reporting on those when something fails, but most of the time when you're performing complex operations and working against a library that you did not build, you have to keep track of everything that is happening yourself so that if something goes wrong, you can report on it properly. Otherwise, you can have some strange errors come up like: "String cannot be empty" with no more information than that... yet in your code, there could be thousands of lines of code where this error could come up, which would make troubleshooting this error a complete nightmare, not to mention reporting the correct verbose information to the user nearly impossible!

Let's take a small example off the top of my head where this would apply... Say you are building an application that takes developer settings for IIS from their dev station, and applying them over to a server somewhere using `Microsoft.Web.Administration`. This would involve multiple objects like `Site`, `ApplicationPool`, `Application`, `VirtualDirectory`, etc... that can contain multiple property values.

Once on the server, you have to take every property value the developer has set and apply them to the actual server, and any one of those actions could fail for one reason or another.

In order to track the progress and/or failures for proper reporting, you will have to implement your own code because the `Microsoft.Web.Administration` library sadly does not provide a lot of details in its exception messages...

The way I've always done this is to keep a local log in the "Apply Settings/Front-end" routine and then use this to know where the code was at when something failed... something like this:

```
try
{
    this.log.Add("Applying pool.Failure.AutoShutdownExe");
    pool.Failure.AutoShutdownExe = this.deployment.WebSite.VirtualDirectory.ApplicationPool.AutoShutdownExe;
    this.log.Add("Successfully applied pool.Failure.AutoShutdownExe");
    //.........
}
catch(exception ex)
{
    this.log.Add("Deploy failure! Fatal error occurred. " + Environment.Newline +
    "Type: " + ex.GetType().Name + Environment.Newline +
    "Message: " + ex.Messsage + Environment.Newline +
    "Stack Trace: " + Environment.Newline + ex.StackTrace);
    //.................
}
```

Which results, in the case of failure at the point demonstrated above, in a great and easy to read log like this:

```
- Deployment starting...
- .....
- .....
- Applying pool.Failure.AutoShutdownExe
- Deploy failure! Fatal error occurred. 
Type: ArgumentNullException
Message: String cannot be empty
Stack Trace:
 ......... Line 35.. .
```

This works great because I can easily see where it failed, but I feel like I spend most of my time writing these logging entries rather than actually coding the functionality itself and I am wondering if there is an easier way to do this? Like moving this tracking functionality to the "Objects" themselves by making them "Self Aware Objects" that track their last accessed property which can then be used to report on later or something?

So what do you usually do?
- Don't verbose track and just blurt out the error and that's it?
- Verbose track in a way similar to what I'm doing above?
- Something completely different?

Is there a standard and proven way of doing this that takes the burden off the developer in any way?

Comment: I think you'll find as you're programming that writing a basic version of a program that does what you want is simple, and you will then spend most of your time "defensive programming" - checking common exceptions, checking conditions where you may need to throw an exception, validating input etc. As an example of this, take a look at [these multiple ways to implement a script](http://www.bolthole.com/solaris/ksh-sampleprog.html).

Comment: While logging is a good thing, a lot of what you are experiencing should be weeded out in unit testing, integration testing, and making sure your inputs are sanitized.

Comment: @mason so what you're saying is that this is normal and comes with the territory once you've been around for a long time... you spend less time coding functionality and more time error handling and reporting "pretty" messages to the user... fair enough. But is there a "standard" way of doing this in C#, that helps the programmer get through this faster and more easily?

Comment: That's exactly what I'm saying. I don't know of any "standards". There may be libraries that use reflection to detect property changes and provide an interface you could plugin to log those changes. And if there's no library, you're free to write one. But it's still going to be up to you to perform defensive coding.

Comment: I am not sure if it fits to your case, but i would refactor the code at most to get smaller classes and methods and rely on stack trace normally. I recommend reading the book "Clean Code", by Robert C. Martin, if you consider this approach can help you.

Comment: thank you folks! Much appreciate your comments and thoughts =)